# I've just created a contract, But the question that remains, how do i put in the total supplys of tokens into the contract? [Hardhat, Openzeppelin]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

I have just been able to deploy the contract into the testnet but as a beforehand noticed, there are no total tokens of Nikola being deployed. Could someone advise me on what I should do to redeploy it with tokens and as this is my code:

I do not expect to create an nft or any take, my goal is token. Part of a financial cryptocurrency project like coinbase is being built. So any advice I get will I reward those who supported me in my first years as a blockchain developer.

```
// contracts/MyNFT.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Nikola is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("Nikola", "NKLO") {
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

visit https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard
and fill the Premint section and that will provide you with the code for pre minted supply to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mint some tokens while deploying to some address preferably the deployer of the contract, for that you need to modify your constructor to look like this & also add a mint function so more tokens can be minted when required

```
address immutable public owner;

constructor(uint256 amount) ERC721("Nikola", "NKLO") {
  owner = msg.sender;
  _mint(msg.sender, amount);
}

function mint(address receiver, uint256 amount) external {
  require(msg.sender == owner, "Owner restricted function");  
  _mint(receiver, amount);
}
```

Also are you sure of using ERC721 here? I mean if you intend to create a publicly distributable token you should use ERC20 instead.